# best way of dealing with O(100K) exact positions

Tags: particles, import

I need to render a particle system comprised of a few hundred thousand particles - but with X, Y, Z positions as given by a table (imported from outside blender in some way via the API). My question is: I've tried looping over the table and creating many small icospheres, but this becomes very slow. Can this be dealt with using a particle system in some way, but specifying the XYZs of the particles 'by hand'? This way, the objects are instances of the same exact object, and then the scene should be simpler to handle memory-wise as no explicit copies of the redundant information are required.

How can I achieve this using the API and the position list that I have? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: [Point Clouds](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/point_cloud.html) could be an option. They are still experimental. But you should be able to render them in Cycles and [import them](https://github.com/SBCV/Blender-Addon-Photogrammetry-Importer/blob/master/photogrammetry_importer/importers/point_importer.py)

Comment: Thanks @Blunder, I will take a look! And: I am also not sure about the downvote. IMHO this is a legitimate question, as the interface gets terribly slow...

Comment: Ah, it seems this is related: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/manipulating-particles-in-python/7552/14 -> and is what I am looking for. Somehow I had missed it. I am going to try :-D

Comment: I found it again. Here is an example video [How to simulate SAND in Blender 3.1?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjM16FUMOKM) It uses the new *Point Cloud* feature that came with 3.1 and a *Manta Flow Liquid* simulation to create the sand with a few million particles. Hope that helps.